# Ajax stops working after one response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery Ajax to post some data from a form. Here is my code.

```
$(() => {
  $("#send-data").on("submit", () => {
    $("#submit-button").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#submit-button").html("SENDING...");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'send.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: $("#send-data").serialize(),
      success: (response) => {
        if (response.indexOf('1900') != -1) {
          $("#submit-button").removeAttr("disabled");
          $("#submit-button").html("SENDING");
          $('.error-msg').css('display', 'none');
          $('.success-msg').css('display', 'inherit');
        } else {
          $("#submit-button").removeAttr("disabled");
          $("#submit-button").html("SENDING");
          $('.success-msg').css('display', 'none');
          $('.error-msg').css('display', 'inherit');
        }
      }
    })

    return false;
  })
})
```

It works fine for first request. But after that response it is not working. The error is `Uncaught TypeError: response.indexOf is not a function`.

response = `{"responseCode":1900}`

I'm sending a request to an API(1), then that API(1) is sending a request to another API(2). That API(2) is giving that JSON response {"responseCode":1900} to API(1). I am getting that response using CURL (PHP). Then I am just sending that response to ajax.

Can anyone please help?

Update: I have solved the problem. The problem was with those APIs.

Comment: response shoul be parse to string , right ?

Comment: Give the data from the response.

Comment: Can you try putting console.log(response) inside the success routine? That way you can log the object itself and see what happens to it after the first request.

Comment: What is the type of your response?

Comment: I'm getting this as a response {"responseCode":1900}

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I have solved the problem. The problem was with those APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, you receive json object not string.

Thus you can do

```
if (response.responseCode != 1900)
```

Comment: Now it's saying undefined (response.responseCode) :/

Comment: Let me tell you the full story. With this ajax I'm sending a request to an API(1), then that API(1) is sending a request to another API(2). That API(2) is giving that JSON response {"responseCode":1900} to API(1). I am getting that response using CURL (PHP). Then I am just sending that response to ajax.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have solved the problem. The problem was with those APIs.